# I moved my craft site to a subdirectory, and things are broken now, help!

Tags: install, redirect, 404

I installed craftcms on a regular .com root folder, and everything worked fine. I can go to .com/news and it will go to my /templates/news.html file, etc.

Now my client wants their site on a subdirectory. I copied over all the files to the new subdirectory, but now when i go to .com/subdirectory/news, I get a 404 page. I checked that the .htaccess was correct, I just don't know what else I have to change to make the new site work on the new subdirectory. Please help!

Comment: Do you get a Craft-styled 404 page (gray background with white box in the middle), or Apache (white background with Times New Roman text)?

Comment: Can you access the cp? - to update: System->General->SiteUrl
and any assets urls affected

Comment: You should also look at the .htaccess rule for the URL rewrites.  You may need to set the basepath

Comment: I get a Craft style template 404 (white background, red box). I have updated the SiteUrl and it effects all my assets, but it does not work on template htmls. I have a feeling there is something I need to change in the database... is there anything there besides SiteUrl? Also, what did you have in mind for .htaccess basepaths?

Comment: *Update*

When I got to www.site.com/subdirectory/test ...it gives me a 404 page template from www.site.com/templates/404.html, not www.site.com/subdirectory/templates/404.html. the subdirectory has it's own .htaccess but it doesn't seem like it's affecting anything...

Comment: I have the same problem but the answer below won't work for me. I created a new .htaccess in the /subdirectory/ root folder (which contains both the 'craft 'and 'public' folder. I changed the basepath in that .htaccess to /subdirectory/public, and left the other .htaccess files unchanged. Foler permissions look right. I'm on MediaTemple grid, so I'm not sure I can change my user/group settings.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out! my htaccess did not have the "." in front of them. So my htaccess in my subdirectory was not being read. Once I renamed it to .htaccess, it worked fine!